# Trying to get property of non-object in simplenews_scheduler_node_page()

Tags: 7

I am using [simplenews_scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler) in Drupal 7 to set up a weekly digest of new content. I am getting the following error on the screen and scheduled newsletters aren't going out, even after running cron. When I send it right away or send it as a test, it goes out and renders just fine.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   simplenews_scheduler_node_page() (line 600
>   sites/all/modules/simplenews_scheduler/simplenews_scheduler.module)

For reference, here is lines 598-601, referenced in the error:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $node = node_load($row->eid);
    $rows[] = array(l($node->title, 'node/' . $row->eid), format_date($row->date_issued, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i'));
  }
```

I'm not sure this error is related as it seems to go only to loading editions already sent.

Drupal 7.65, simplenews 7.x-1.1, simplenews_scheduler 7.x-1.0-beta2

Does anyone know what could be causing this error or an alternative to sending a scheduled mailing? The module makes a copy of a base node each for each edition so it's kind of nice.

Comment: You should check if $node is an Object under the node_load() line.

Comment: What does this mean? How do I do that?

Comment: if (is_object($node)) {
  $rows[] = array(l($node->title, 'node/' . $row->eid), format_date($row->date_issued, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i'));
}

Maybe you should open an issue on drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you saying that the code is wrong? What is the code in your comment? Why would I be the only person to have this issue?

Comment: I say that $node could be null in certain circumstances and the code you wrote above will try to get an object property "$node->title" which will error if $node is != object. I dont know your setup so I cant tell you what is going wrong on your side.
You could also try to debug this with xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by deleting the node (master newsletter) and creating a new one. I had probably deleted a previous test edition, which caused it to start delivering the error. If there is only one test edition, don't delete it even if the master is preserved.